# How can I limit the value of my bank account tied to PayPal?

Tags: paypal, bank-account, limits

How can I limit the value of my bank account tied to PayPal?

Comment: I may be a bit naive. Why would you want to?

Comment: @Renesis Risk mitigation, perhaps?

Comment: @Chris, yes, I would guess that much, but risk of what? I'm wondering if there are risks of the ACH system or Paypal's use of it that are unknown to me.

Comment: Perhaps if the PayPal account were compromised (hacked), it would limit the amount of funds that could be transferred out.

Comment: Paypal and eBay both allow a 2nd level of authentication.  You can get a battery powered credit card or a smart phone app that generates secrets you will need to enter. A pain, but you get used to it.  The real pain is when the battery powered secret card dies and you need to undo the security....

Comment: @Chris - And does something of the nature of Paypal make that scenario a higher risk than for standard banks? Or is this a comment on ACH-linked accounts in general?

Comment: @Renesis PayPal is a popular service, hence a popular target.  Phishing scams, for one.  Of course that doesn't mean there aren't other targets in the system.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, you can't.  Don't link your primary checking account to PayPal.  Open a separate bank account like ING Direct and keep very little balance.  I wrote about this a while back in [my blog](http://www.moneycone.com/should-you-link-paypal-to-your-main-checking-account/).

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the value of your checking account tied to paypal by not putting money in that account.

In fact, you should always limit the balance in your checking account to what you plan to spend, plus a reasonable buffer. Anything you have above and being that should be in separate accounts (both to minimize exposure as well as maximize your interest earned).

Comment: Many banks will waive fees if you keep a certain minimum balance. With interest rates so low, it is generally more cost-effective to ensure you meet this minimum balance rather than moving the money out into an account that pays interest.